# WAMPserver - Set root to localhost/mysite (broken images)

Tags: localhost, wamp, directory-structure, document-root

Does anyone know the easiest way to do this? My current setup is creating a situation where images don't work depending on whereabouts in the site I am.

For example:
`./wp-content/images/image.png` will work on the homepage, but break once on products pages etc.

When I try using just `/wp-content/images/image.png` it still ends up broken as the URL comes back as `http://localhost/wp-content...` rather than `http://localhost/mysite/wp-content`

Hope that makes sense. This would save a lot of hassle across multiple sites for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create a Virtual Host as suggested? Specially for WordPress it is almost obligatory

Comment: @RiggsFolly yup, but the regular ``/wp-content..`` url still defaults to localhost rather than localhost/mysite

Comment: If you created a virtualhost, you should also install into that VH, so there should be no reference to `localhost` at all even if the actual folder holding the site is below the `\wamp64\www\` folder

Comment: @RiggsFolly so all of my files are located in /www/mysite however it still doesn't seem to be working. How should my wp-config file and wp-site/wp-options tables look?

Comment: My point was if you install WP into the VH you wont get refernces to localhost.

Comment: Is this a brand new install or are you moving a site to local PC to develop it?